# Unknown or unsupported property value '0xA00000C' for _NT_TARGET_VERSION and Target OS Windows10

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wdk

I am building my project in VS2019 and it gives me this error. Unknown or unsupported property value '0xA00000C' for _NT_TARGET_VERSION and Target OS Windows10. I am using Win10 SDK and Windows 10, version 22H2 WDK.

Earlier I was using VS2022 with Win11 SDK and Windows 11, version 22H2 WDK and it was compiling fine. Now when I want to downgrade to VS2019, with older SDK and WDK as mentioned, it gives me the error.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Win10 Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
<TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
<UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries> 
<PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
<ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
<DriverType>WDM</DriverType>
<NETADAPTER_VERSION_MAJOR>6</NETADAPTER_VERSION_MAJOR> 
<NETADAPTER_VERSION_MINOR>0</NETADAPTER_VERSION_MINOR>
<ALLOW_DATE_TIME>1</ALLOW_DATE_TIME>
<DriverTargetPlatform>Desktop</DriverTargetPlatform> 
<_NT_TARGET_VERSION>0xA00000C</_NT_TARGET_VERSION></PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Win10 is 0xA00, couldn't guess what 0xA00000C was intended to do.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant , after changing nt_target_version to 0xA00 it got build successfully.